# 2d Collision Detection - Trying To Get All The Non Transparent Pixels Of Two Sprites

Tags: java, sprite, collision, detection

I am in the process of building a 2d game and I am trying to implement pixel level/perfect collision detection.

My problem is I am trying to get all the non transparent pixels of my sprites by using the Buffered Image classes getRGB() method however I can only use this method on Buffered Images.

I was hoping you could point me in the right direction as to what I am trying to do. Below are the methods of my game class I am working in:

**This Method Is Supposed To Get All The Non Transparent Pixels In My Sprite**

```
public HashSet<String> getMask(Sprite character){

HashSet <String> mask = new HashSet<String>();
    int pixel;
    int alpha;

    for(int i = 0; i < character.getWidth(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < character.getHeight(); i++){   

            pixel = character.getRGB(i,j);
            alpah = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;    

            if(alpha != 0){
                mask.add((character.getX + i) + "," + (character.getY - j));
            }
        }
    }
    return mask;
}
```

**Method To Check The Collisions**

```
public boolean checkCollision(Sprite a, Sprite b){      
    // This method detects to see if the images overlap at all. If they do,     collision is possible
    int ax1 = a.getX();
    int ay1 = a.getY();
    int ax2 = ax1 + a.getWidth();
    int ay2 = ay1 + a.getHeight();
    int bx1 = b.getX();
    int by1 = b.getY();
    int bx2 = bx1 + b.getWidth();
    int by2 = by1 + b.getHeight();

    if(by2 < ay1 || ay2 < by1 || bx2 < ax1 || ax2 < bx1){
          return false; // Collision is impossible.
    }
    else {// Collision is possible.
        // get the masks for both images
        HashSet<String> maskPlayer1 = getMask(shark);
        HashSet<String> maskPlayer2 = getMask(torpedo);

        maskPlayer1.retainAll(maskPlayer2);  // Check to see if any pixels in maskPlayer2 are the same as those in maskPlayer1

        if(maskPlayer1.size() > 0){  // if so, than there exists at least one pixel that is the same in both images, thus
            System.out.println("Collision" + count);//  collision has occurred.
            count++;
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

In the getMask() method above you can see that I am saying:   character.getRGB() however because character is of type Sprite I am getting an error as I  can only use getRGB() with a buffered image.

So as far as I am aware the getRGB() is happy to get the current pixels that the buffered image is moving over in the game but not happy to get the current pixels for a Sprite. I could be misunderstanding how this method works?

So I am wondering if there is any way around this error or if not, would you be able to point me in the right direction

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Sprite is some class that extends Rectangle or has such properties.

You can add a BufferedImage member to it: whenever you get the RGB from the character you get it from that BufferedImage

```
int getRGB(int i, int j) {
  return myBufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
}
```

where you have in Sprite

```
class Sprite {

  BufferedImage myBufferedImage;


  public int getRGB(int i, int j) {

    ......... as shown above

  }

  ....


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Do you mean set myBufferedImage to be a global variable? If I was to post my entire game class would you be able to help me understand

Comment: Sure, give me 5 minuets

Comment: would it be okay If I could send you an email with the classes that are involved as my animation class is used also and all 3 classes are together are very large. And I feel maybe to large to post here